# What is the restriction of the tangent bundle on a projective space to a rational curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Fix a base field $k$. Let $i:C(\simeq\mathbb{P}^1) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$ be a rational curve on a projective space.
Is there a formula about $i^*T_{\mathbb{P}^n}$?

Comment: That depends on the curve.

Comment: If $C$ has degree $1$, is there a formula about $i^∗T_{\mathbb{P}^n}$?

Comment: If $C$ is a line, then $i^*T_{\mathbb{P}^n} \cong \mathcal{O}(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}(1)^{\oplus (n-1)}$.

Comment: Could you please give me a reference? I would like to understand how to show it.

Comment: See, for instance, Okonek, Christian; Schneider, Michael; Spindler, Heinz. Vector bundles on complex projective spaces.

Comment: @user145752 the normal bundle of a line in P^n is n-1 copies of O(1). Now $ i^* \mathbb{P}^n $ sits in between O(2) and the normal bundle, so has to be the direct sum because of vanishing Ext..